# Different permalink structure per category

Tags: permalinks

Just for curiosity, is it possible to have a different permalink scheme for different templates or categories?

For example, for post "XYZ leach review" in category pets/dogs to have "mysite.com/reviews/pets/dogs/xyz_leach_review.php" and then any post in another category to be "mysite.com/justthecastegory/the_post_name.php"?

Answer (score 2):

By Design, there is one permalink structure for the whole wordpress site. What you try to achieve needs to introduce a custom permalink structure for a part of it.

This is not trivial because you need to introduce your own permalinks via rewrites ([Rewrite API (Wordpress Codex)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API)) and you need to change the links to those pages when linked on occasion. This can be done with hooks for the appropriate functions. E.g. for  [get_category_link()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_link) you can make use of the `category_link` filter.

I haven't done this yet for a larger part of a site and I assume that it can introduce problems as you need to take care of multiple places to have it working properly. I don't want to say it's not possible but just a reminder of the side-effects this can have.